# Get Page Type Of Referer Url In Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, redirect, page, link

I am using Magento 2.3.5-p2

I am trying to get the page type for previous link

I am able to get the previous link using

```
\Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect,

public function getPreviousPageType(){
        return $this->_redirect->getRefererUrl();
    }
```

but I want this to return the page type instead of the page url so I will receive something like

'catalog_product_view' ,
'catalog_category_view',
'cms_index_index'

but I am not able to find how to get the page type from the referer url

Any help is kindly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the urlFinderInterface to get an url rewrite associated with a specified path which will return you an url rewrite object containing the entity type of the requested path. The code below is not perfect but it gives you an idea of what should be done

```
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlFinderInterface $urlFinder
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    )
    {
        $this->urlFinder = $urlFinder;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;

    }

    public function getPreviousPageType(){
        //You might have to parse the referer url here to get something without domain name and store code
        $requestPath = $this->_redirect->getRefererUrl();
        $storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId()
        $urlObject = $this->findUrlFromRequestPath($requestPath,$storeId);
        return $urlObject->getEntityType();
    }

     /**
     * Find a url from a request url on the current store
     *
     * @param string $requestPath
     * @param int $storeId
     * @return UrlRewrite|null
     */
    public function findUrlFromRequestPath(string $requestPath, int $storeId): ?UrlRewrite
    {
        return $this->urlFinder->findOneByData(
            [
                'request_path' => $requestPath,
                'store_id' => $storeId
            ]
        );
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I will test this later, I am able to find other alternative before this which is saving the value to customersession then retreiving it back but this seems to be a better alternative